# Google Sheet data Apps Script not showing values in WebApps

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am having a problem passing the values from Google Sheet to my WebApps html upon a search function. My google script file managed to look for the value and passed it in an array, but my javascript file is unable to pass the values back to my page.

I am really a coding beginner here trying to build a simple application as I learn along. Can anyone guide me?

.js file:

```
//Retrieve Customer
function getCustomer() {
  
  var searchId = document.getElementById("search").value;
  
  if (searchId.length > 8){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(custDetail).getCustDetail(searchId);
  } 
  
}

//Success Handler
function custDetail(cust){

  document.getElementById("idv-introducer").value = cust.custIntroducer;
  document.getElementById("idvname").value = cust.custName;
  document.getElementById("idv-id").value = cust.custId;
  document.getElementById("dob").value = cust.custDob;
  document.getElementById("nationality").value = cust.custNationality;
  document.getElementById("gender").value = cust.custGender;
  document.getElementById("marital").value = cust.custMarital;
  document.getElementById("address").value = cust.custAddress;
  document.getElementById("postalcode").value = cust.custPostal;
  document.getElementById("idvemail").value = cust.custEmail;
  document.getElementById("idvcontact").value = cust.custContact;
  document.getElementById("licensedate").value = cust.custLicense;
  document.getElementById("category").value = cust.custCategory;
  M.updateTextFields();
  
}
```

.gs file:

```
function getCustDetail(search) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("idvData");
  var idvCustData = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),13).getValues();
  
  var custNameList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var custIdList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  var custDobList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });
  var custNationalityList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[3]; });
  var custGenderList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[4]; });
  var custMaritalList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[5]; });
  var custAddressList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[6]; });
  var custPostalList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[7]; });
  var custEmailList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[8]; });
  var custContactList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[9]; });
  var custLicenseList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[10]; });
  var custIntroducerList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[11]; });
  var custCategoryList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[12]; });
  
  var searchPostion = custIdList.indexOf(search);
  var custDetail = {};
  custDetail.custName = custNameList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custId = custIdList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custDob = custDobList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custNationality = custNationalityList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custGender = custGenderList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custMarital = custMaritalList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custAddress = custAddressList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custPostal = custPostalList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custEmail = custEmailList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custContact = custContactList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custLicense = custLicenseList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custIntroducer = custIntroducerList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custCategory = custCategoryList[searchPostion];
  Logger.log(searchPostion);
  Logger.log(custDetail);
  Logger.log(search);
  
  if (searchPostion > -1){
  
   return  custDetail;
   
  } else {
    return '-';
  
  }
}
```

My logs did capture the values. Did I missed out anything?

html:

```
<!-- Header Start -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s9">
                <h5>General Info</h5>
             
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <select id="category">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Option</option>
                <option value="MTP">Private</option>
                <option value="MTC">Commercial</option>
              </select>
              <label>Motor Category</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s9">
              <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="tab col s3 "><a href="#individual" class="grey-text text-darken-4">Individual</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#corporate" class="grey-text text-darken-4">Corporate</a></li>
                
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input id="search" type="search">
              <label for="search">Search ID</label>
              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Header End -->

          <!-- Individual Tab -->
            <form id="individual">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s3 offset-s9">
                  <label for="idv-introducer">Introducer</label>  
                  <input id="idv-introducer" type="text" class="autocomplete">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  
                  <label for="idvname">Insured Name</label>
                  <input id="idvname" type="text" class="validate">
                  <span class="helper-text" data-error="Required" data-success=""></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  <input id="idv-id" type="text">
                  <label for="idv-id">NRIC / UEN</label>
                  <span class="helper-text" data-error="Required" data-success=""></span>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  
                  <label for="dob">DOB (DD/MM/YYYY)</label>
                  <input type="text" id="dob" class="datepicker">
                  <span class="helper-text" data-error="Required" data-success=""></span>
                </div>
              
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input id="nationality" type="text">
                  <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  <select id="gender">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Option</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                  </select>
                  <label>Gender</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  <select id="marital">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Option</option>
                    <?!= maritalList;?>
                  </select>
                  <label>Marital Status</label>
                </div>
              
            

                <div class="input-field col s9">
                  <textarea id="address" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                  <label for="address">Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  <label for="postalcode" >Postal Code</label>
                  <input id="postalcode" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{6}">
                  <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input id="idvemail" type="email" class="validate">
                  <label for="idvemail">Email</label>
                  <span class="helper-text" data-error="Invalid Email" data-success=""></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  
                  <input id="idvcontact" type="text">
                  <label for="idvcontact">Contact No.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  <label for="licensedate">License (DD/MM/YYYY)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="licensedate">
                  <span class="helper-text" data-error="Required" data-success=""></span>
                </div>
              <div class="right-align">
                 <button id="btn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="action">Add</button>
              </div>
             </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: If you print cust on your custDetail() function, what does it show?

Comment: What is the tagName of the elements to which you want to assign values (e.g. `idv-introducer`)? `div`?`span`?`input`?

Comment: The custDetail() print out an array of the customer details. Tag name of the element to assign values are all input tag. May refer below for my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `value` of HTML elements, works only for certain tags (e.g. `<input>`).

### For most HTML tags, you need to set [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead.

Sample:

```
document.getElementById("idv-introducer").innerHTML = cust.custIntroducer;
```

### UPDATE

Another error source is passing objects from serverside to clientside.

This problem can be solved by wrapping the objects into strings before passing them from a `code.gs` function to the Javascript function.

For this replace

`return  custDetail;`

with

`JSON.stringify(custDetail);`

and within the Javascript function `function custDetail(cust)`

define

`cust = JSON.parse(cust);`.

Comment: But I am using the input tag. Do I still use innerHTML?

Comment: No, for `input` you do not need to - this is why I ask asking which tags you are using. However - the rest of your code works for me - why don't you log all the object entries clientide within `function custDetail(cust)`, e.g. :`console.log("cust.custName: " + cust.custName);` - to make sure they have all been passed correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know how to console.log in the client side here. Does it shows in the stackdriver log? Because it did not reflect anything there with the console log, even if I just log a string.

Comment: If it's clientside, you cannot see it in the Stackdriver logs, but in the browser developper console. To see it - e.g. for Chrome, you can press F12 or go on `Tools->Developer tools`.

Comment: In the console log, I keep having this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'custIntroducer' of null. But, the problem is the Stackdriver log is able to log the values.

Comment: Can you log all the other values in the the console log?

Comment: Okay, here is what I have tested out: 
1) console log other values - Yes. 
2) try to search a value that does not exist in my sheet, which will gives my searchPosition to < -1, returns undefined and shown in my webapp.
3) search a value that exist - nothing came out, not even the console log.

Comment: To 3) Do you mean that you cannot see any logs from the JS function `custDetail()`? Once again, those logs are NOT in the stack driver logs, they are in your browser developer console.

Comment: Yea, there is no logs from the JS Function custDetail() in the browser developer console. Only error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'custIntroducer' of null.

Comment: And if you log `custDetail.custIntroducer` within `function getCustDetail(search)` it logs as intended? Can you log `typeof custDetail.custIntroducer` and verify that it is a string?

Comment: Yes it is. Just cannot find out what is the issue

Comment: Could you provide me a sample sheet for testing to see if I can reproduce the issue wiht your sheet?

Comment: Sure, do I just share it to your email ziganotschka@gmail.com? I will generate some dummy data inside.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue only if I drew and assign the values form the sheet, rather than assigning hardcoded strings to your object. While I am not sure why the problem arises only in this case there is a workaround: JSON stringify the data before passing it from serverside to clientside. `return  JSON.stringify(custDetail);` and then `cust = JSON.parse(cust);.` This solves the problem!

Comment: Wonderful! This solves the problem! Guess I really have to read up on JSON to understand how it works. Now I just need to figure out how to pass the value to my select tag. Thanks for the fix!